# Symfony - load event listeners for one bundle

Tags: symfony, event-handling

Is there a way to load all event listeners for a given bundle?
I just found this approach:

`$evd = $this->get('event_dispatcher'); $listeners = $evd->getListeners();`

I have in my bundle a couple of listeners in the EventListener folder and now I want to iterate through all files in this folder and load one method.

Cheers for help

Comment: Nothing built in however there are [various approaches](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html) to dealing with groups of services.